# Customize Page to Request access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access, access-denied, customization

This is more for getting advise on a way to go on Access Request procedures:

Currently we are using the default OOB "Access Denied, click here to request access" which is fine.

But we do get a couple of customers stating that the user didn't know exactly where to get access...just a general area, the customer doesn't know which group a user is requesting, general instructions for the users, etc.

Would it be ok to create a "Request Access" page...more friendly looking, with some instructions then it links to a task list where folks will get notified?  Where I work, we don't have access to SharePoint Designer, VS, or other web/application authoring software...just notepad or notepad++.

Just curious what other folks are doing out there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps:

1. Navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ folder, then create a new folder named as “CustomPages”.
   In the LAYOUTS folder copy the file AccessRequests.ASPX into the CustomPages subfolder, renaming it AccessRequestsNew.ASPX.
2. Edit this new page and add text or other HTML elements within  tags inthis page.
3. After completing the modification on this WFE, copy the CustomPages subfolder into the LAYOUTS folder of each of the WFEs in your farm.
4. Then use Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage command in SharePoint Management Shell to apply this custom page.

More information you can check the posts:

[change access request page in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183341/change-access-request-page-in-sharepoint-2013)

[SharePoint 2013: how to create a custom access denied page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31253.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-access-denied-page.aspx)